# Adding a new project in remote bazaar repository from my system

Tags: bazaar

There is remote bazaar repository. There I have to add a new project in the some existing category from my system in the bazaar.  I have read the bazaar documentation. But still, i was not able to get the grasp of it how to add the new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've created a branch locally, then "bzr push " should be sufficient.

If that doesn't work, can you give a bit more background on the layout of your project on the remote server?